# Fulfilling NAs based on symmetry

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, transformation

Imagine you have a large dataset similar to the matrix M below:

```
M <- data.frame(code = c("001", "001", "002", "002", "003", "003"), 
                decr = c("x", NA, "y", "y", NA, "z"))

# M

#   code decr
# 1  001    x
# 2  001 <NA>
# 3  002    y
# 4  002    y
# 5  003 <NA>
# 6  003    z
```

I would like to fulfill the NAs in the following intuitive form:

```
#   code decr
# 1  001    x
# 2  001    x
# 3  002    y
# 4  002    y
# 5  003    z
# 6  003    z
```

How would it be possible to do this transformation optimally?

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); M %>% group_by(code) %>% fill(decr) %>% fill(decr, .direction = 'up')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

M <- data.frame(code = c("001", "001", "002", "002", "003", "003"), 
                decr = c("x", NA, "y", "y", NA, "z"))

M %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate (decr=unique(na.omit(decr)))
```

This is similar to @Sotos answer, and that in the dupe, but it does not assume a particular location for the missing values.

Comment: Nice. You should add this answer to the dupe as well

Comment: Nice! I got something similar: `M %>% group_by(code) %>% mutate(decr = if_else(is.na(decr), unique(na.omit(decr)), decr))`. But I see now that the NA-check is obsolete if you just overwrite the whole group.

Comment: I guess this only works as expected if there's a 1 to 1 relation between both columns

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes - there has to be one to one. If not the `fill` method makes more sense - assuming the "good" value is always above or below the `NA`'s

Comment: Just checked, dupe and this answer won't work - there is not a one ot one relationship between groups and values there.